# Acessar WebService localhost - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, web-service, android-studio, asp

Possuo um webservice que foi feito em ASP.NET no VisualStudio 2013, estou rodando ele localmente (localhost), e não estou conseguindo acessa-lo no emulador android do Android Studio, e nem no meu dispositivo físico (Depuração de USB).

Eu tentei utilizar o IP 10.0.2.2 para o emulador padrão do Android Studio, e 10.0.3.2 para o emulador do Genymotion, porém eu recebo uma excessão de java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa questão?

Comment: consegue colocar o Log do AndroidStudio? Se vc tentar acessar a **URL** no navegador?  Seu app possui permissão de acesso a internet?

Comment: Olá Thiago, sim, ele possui permissão normal. Eu ja tive esse problema no xamarin, utilizava o emuladro do visual studio, e configurei ele manualmente, configurei o do genymotion, e nada tambem..

Answer (score 3):

caso vc use windows va ate o cmd e digite ipconfig e entao o ip que aparece na sua maquina coloque no lugar do ip local 10.0.2.2 o seu ip que encontrou no linux e um processo parecido so que no terminal e digite ifconfig.
Qualquer coisa so falar!

Comment: Igor, bom dia! Já fiz isso tambem, e não funcionou. Obrigado..

Comment: Igor, obrigado, deu certo cara. Precisava executar o visual studio como administrador, agora funcionou.

Comment: Que bom! precisando so postar no stack